# webpack-dev-server cannot get /?

Tags: web, webpack, webpack-dev-server

### **This is my webpack.config.js**

### devserver:

```
devServer: {
   contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
   compress: true,
   port: 9000
},
```

### output:

```
 output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/[name].min.js',
    },
```

### package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "watch": "webpack --watch",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
        "build": "webpack --env.production"
}
```

the browser always cannot get / when I ran npm start.

### git bash

[image: git bash result]

### browser console

[image: browser console]

Comment: try adding  publicPath: '/' to your output

Comment: I tried,but 'cannot get /'.Now only I run 'npm run build' first ,the webpack-dev-server  can find my project.

Comment: I recommend posting your question here - https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues.  They may be able to help you out if you display your entire webpackconfig.js file